# Watson Speech to Text - status: 401, error: Unauthorized

Tags: speech-recognition, chatbot, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I am trying to integrate the speech to text service in my chatbot but receiving the error metioned in the title. I just used the service like described in the documentation. They changed the authorisation method from username + password to api key right?
This is the error I get:

```
Feb 26, 2019 11:18:38 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: --> POST https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize http/1.1 (-1-byte body)
Feb 26, 2019 11:18:40 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: <-- 401 Unauthorized https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize (2434ms, 37-byte body)
Feb 26, 2019 11:18:40 AM com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService processServiceCall
SEVERE: POST https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize, status: 401, error: Unauthorized
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.exception.UnauthorizedException: Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. Tip: Did you set the Endpoint?
    at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.processServiceCall(WatsonService.java:368)
    at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService$WatsonServiceCall.execute(WatsonService.java:429)
    at STTService.erkenneAudio(STTService.java:66)
    at GUI$recordAudioButtonListener.actionPerformed(GUI.java:179)
```

Nevertheless, this is what my code looks like:

```
    SpeechToText stt = new SpeechToText();

    stt.setApiKey("3PHwb6P36A0hgiovasdcqgesVyDZEO7awg2L1be");
    stt.setEndPoint("https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api");

    try {
        RecognizeOptions recognizeOptions = new RecognizeOptions.Builder()
                  .audio(new File("C:/Users/jvermaet/Desktop/hallo.wav"))
                  .contentType(HttpMediaType.AUDIO_WAV)
                  .build();

        SpeechRecognitionResults srr = stt.recognize(recognizeOptions).execute();
        System.out.println(srr.toString());
                    
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("OO");
    }
```

Comment: I see the actual apices in your code above, maybe you do not want to share that in a public forum.

Comment: I just changed them to some random characters.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to use the IAmOptions Contructor. If you cannot import the IAmOptions it might be because you use an old version of the sdk, which was my main problem.

```
IamOptions options = new IamOptions.Builder()
.apiKey("{apikey}")
.build();
Assistant assistant = new Assistant("{version}", options);
assistant.setEndPoint("{url}");
```

Comment: Can you give an example to help future users?

Comment: I extended my answer